# How to access command from MainWindow level in another Window?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am trying to access commands that are defined in MainWindow.xaml in another window. I am only able to get grayed out titles of these commands. I am wondering what should be should be done in order to get a full access.

Sample of the command:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static RoutedUICommand AddCommand1 = new RoutedUICommand("Command ", "command1", typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(AddCommand1, AddCommand1Executed));
    }

    private void AddCommand1Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewItem picker = new AddNewItem();
        picker.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I access these command in style through databinding:

```
<Menu x:Name="TaskMenuContainer"><MenuItem x:Name="menuItem" Header="TASKS" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Template="{DynamicResource TaskMenuTopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}">
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

These commands work in pages that is loaded inside MainWindow.xaml through frame. However, if I have pop up window that is not part of MainWindow.xaml these commands are only grayed out and not functional anymore (cannot be executed). Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you define the command, you define it for a particular window. If you want to handle the command globally, at the application level, you can use `CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding`:

First, define you command in a separate static class:

```
public static class GlobalCommands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand AddCommand1 = new RoutedUICommand("Command ", "command1", typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

Then, in you window or whatever place you want to put the command logic, register the command handlers:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static MainWindow()
    {
       CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), new CommandBinding(GlobalCommands.AddCommand1, AddCommand1Executed, CanAddExecute));
    }

    private static void AddCommand1Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewItem picker = new AddNewItem();
        picker.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And in your menu style you should change the binding to `x:Static`:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{x:Static my:GlobalCommands.AddCommand1}" />
```

When the command is routed, when checking for command bindings in each active element in the UI, the bindings registered for each element's class will also be checked. By registering the binding here, you can cause every instance of a class to be able to handle the specific command.

So, in the above example, the type `Window` is used and this will cause the routing to find the command binding in *any* instance of `Window`, once the routing reaches that instance in its search for a command binding.

You could instead, for example, restrict the handling to a specific subclass of `Window`, so that the command will only be bound in an instance of that subclass. Or you can use some other UI element type, so that that the presence of that specific type of element will cause the event to be handled. Just set the owning type for the registered command binding appropriately for your specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I added Menu style with databinding I have. Please look in my edited question. I am wondering your technique will work in my case. Thank you again!

Comment: See my update. You should bind the command using the x:Static extension.

Comment: I made it work with your technique. Thank you again for the tip. I only have a question if I can to have the public MainWindow () defenition instead of static MainWindow() that you suggested in you sample. Can this cause any issues? I cannot change it in my solutuion since I have other things going on there. Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: You can use "public MainWindow ()" for that as long as you your window is created once in your application life cycle. Otherwise the handler will be registered more than once.